# Open Help web page from Google script HTMLservice interface

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to put a Help button on an HTMLservice interface.  I have tried it directly on the button and also by calling the function below

```
function helpClicked() {
    document.getElementById('payment').value = "Help Clicked...";
    window.open("www.google.com")

}
```

This changes the payment field to validate that the button was clicked but does not open a new browser window with the url.  Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: Use a link with the correct URL directly instead of a button and use css to make it look like a button (if you need one). You can still hook triggers to the link, but you won't need to do the `window.open` yourself.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you for getting me outside that box I was in!

Comment: @Henrique : you should make it an answer (eventually with a code snippet) so that it can be accepted and upvoted ;)

Comment: @Serge Done. I guess since my answer was a single line, I thought it fitted better on a comment, I usually don't like such short answers, but if it solved the question... well,  let's promote it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a link (`a` tag) directly with the correct URL instead of a button and use css to make it look like a button (if you need one). You can still hook triggers to the link, but you won't need to do the `window.open` yourself, therefore avoiding this problem/limitation.